# Copy entire rows from one sheet to another if certain cell in first sheet does NOT contain certain text value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have two sheets.
The first one has incoming data that dynamically updates. The fields are `Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`.
I want to duplicate the rows in a second sheet but only if the email field in sheet 1 does NOT end with or contain "@gmail.com".

Any idea on how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `importrange` + `regexmatch`

Don't forget to allow access to connect the two sheets.

```
=filter(
IMPORTRANGE(SHEET URL,"Sheet2!A1:A3"),
not(arrayformula(regexmatch(IMPORTRANGE(SHEET URL,"Sheet2!A1:A3"),"@gmail\.com")))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *...The fields are Name, Last Name, Email. I want to duplicate the **rows**...*

Please try the following formula *(where `Col3` is the `Email` one)*:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","range_string"),"where NOT Col3 contains '@gmail.com'")
```

*(Do not forget to adjust the formula ranges accordingly)*

Comment: The formula now works as expected. Forgot the `NOT`:/